# Share the image via Mail in android

Tags: android

In my android application, I share the image via Bluetooth is working. At the same time i tried to share via mail. But image isn't attached that mail. It's only send with body. 
Any Solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To send image via email as an attachment, you first need to save it as a file on the SD card. If your image is a `Bitmap` then you can write it to a file like below

```
OutputStream fOut = null;
String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myImage.png";
File file = new File(fileName);
fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
```

Then using the `Intent`, launch the email client application with the image file as an attachment

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {""}); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, EMAIL_SUBJECT); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, EMAIL_BODY);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+fileName));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Sharing Options"));
```